# How to fetch a particular value in a python tuple?

Tags: python, tuples

So far I've learnt how to fetch value in a tuple with variables like：

```
def x(a):
    return (a-1,a,a+1)

bottom, middle, top = x(100)
```

But what should I do if I only want to get the third value 'a+1' in the tuple?

Comment: Have you tried indexing it yet?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, sorry, I assume it's different with dictionary and list, thus I didn't try index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x(100)` returns a tuple, so just index it if you want to us just one value:

```
top = x(100)[2]
```

Demo:

```
>>> def x(a):
...     return (a - 1, a, a + 1)
... 
>>> top = x(100)[2]
>>> top
101
```

Other options include slicing; get the last two values:

```
middle, top = x(100)[1:]
```

or ignore the middle value:

```
bottom, _, top = x(100)
```

where `_` is just a regular variable, but by convention is often used to signify an assignment that will otherwise be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Tuple also have index values

so to get a specific element of a tuple known its index you can use tuple[index]
what you do in your code you assign three variables values from a tuple at the same time
so

```
bottom, middle, top = x(100)
```

is actually

```
bottom = x(100)[0]
middle = x(100)[1]
top = x(100)[2]
```

to see what you can do with tuples(methods etc.), look at its documentation either on web, or by `help(tuple)`

Comment: Except that it only calls the function once.